# virus attack to the website and it is not showing anything

Tags: php, web-applications, cakephp, web, virus

I have a web application which is developed in cakePHP, but from last few week, a virus is affected to the site and its not showing any pages. even if we go to the source code, nothing is there to display.

I have checked the index.php, there is no extra entry. Can some help me to find out the solution. and, how can i prevent these virus attacks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be better asked on Serverfault.com

Comment: how do you know it was virus?

Comment: When was the last time you made changes to the web app? Last week by any chance?

Comment: -1 for asking on the wrong forum, but if your files didn't change, it still could be a) the web server itself being changed (direct attack on binaries, config, rootkits...) b) the database changed which crashes your page to render (typical XSS attempt) c) it is not an attack at all, something just went wrong (permissions, config, directory structure, some quota filled up...)

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that you have a virus, then I cannot help you.

If there is a chance that its not a virus...

If you are running PHP, a 'white blank page' can be a symptom of a syntax error.

Somewhere in your code there may be a typo.

**Ensure you can spot errors**

Try:

- turning on 'display errors'

  - http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors
- setting 'error reporting' to display all type of errors

  - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Temporally add this to the top of your script

```
<?php

//ensure errors are displayed
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//show all type of errors apart from Notices
error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE);
```

---

Also try removing the closing php tags from the bottom of pure-php scripts:

i.e change:

```
<?php

//i am 100% php

?>
```

to

```
<?php

//i am 100% php
```

Obviously, keep a closing php tag if it separates php from html.

This is a common coding-practice.

See, for example:
 - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html#coding-standard.php-file-formatting.general

**Start debugging**

A bit of brute force might help. Start at the top of the script and add something like:

```
<?php

//ensure errors are displayed
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//show all type of errors apart from Notices
error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE);

echo('hello - i got this far');
exit;

//...other code
```

Refresh the page. If you can see

```
hello - i got this far
```

Then you know that it is a problem that you can solve.

Tidy-up / comment-out those lines of code, mentioned above.

Then look into:

*Debugging And The Scientific Method*

- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DebuggingAndTheScientificMethod

Answer (score 0):

Check both the server's error logs and the PHP error log. No output in the browser generally indicates there's a problem with the script and "display_errors" is off, so you get nothing sent.